# How do you get the current RTT estimation for a tcp socket?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, posix

Specifically in C, for *nix systems.

Comment: If you are asking how to get the RTT that the TCP stack has calculated for a given socket, you can't do it. Of course you can measure it yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the linux-specific socket option `TCP_INFO` for that (defined in `linux/tcp.h`)

```
struct tcp_info ti;
socklen_t tisize = sizeof(ti);
getsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_INFO, &ti, &tisize);
```

Now the rtt-estimation is in `ti.tcpi_rtt` (unit is milliseconds). There are several more interesting values, just look into the structure tcp_info.

Comment: Thx, this looks perfect, any chance it'll work on windows?

I did find an alternative method, but it would be nice if I could ignore the OS all together.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb485738(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Keynan I think this is very linux specific. Indeed I would be very surprised if such functionality would be found in any standard like posix or similar, it's much too specialized for that.

Comment: Does anyone probably know where can I find all these metrics documented. My `/usr/include/linux/tcp.h` is not very generous on explanations.